# How to debug Asp.Net JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Getting this bizarre error.

I think it's caused by a bad response to a partial postback for an Update Panel

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Details: Error parsing near '

### I'll improve the question / and answer once I understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was fiddler.   You can see the response which in my case included the exact error (a duplicate control name embedded in a gridview).